# Confused on how to initialize class members

Tags: c++, class

Let's say I'm working with a class called Engine. From what I understand is that the way to initialize this class and create a new object can be done like the following:

```
string type = "v8";
Engine engine(type);
```

This creates a new Engine object...
So now what if I have a second class called Car which has a member of the Engine class:

Car.h

```
class Car
{
    private:
        Engine engine;
    public:
        Car();
}
```

Car.cpp

```
Car::Car() {
    // Need to initialize Engine
}
```

How would I initialize member engine, isn't it already initialized from the header file? I'm confused because if Engine has polymorphic constructors where one constructor Engine() and another Engine(string), wouldn't it be initialized in the Car header? How do I tell Car that I want an empty Engine member that will be initialized in Car's constructor

Answer (score 2):

It works like this:

```
Car::Car(void) : engine("whatever you want")
{
}
```

This tells how to initialize the members of your class.
Different Car constructor overloads can initialize your engine in different ways

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options (as of C++11).

You can use an in-class initializer. Like this:

```
struct A {
    int i = 42;
};
```

You can use the member initialization list. Like this:

```
struct B {
B() : i{42} {}
    int i;
};
```

Or you can assign the member in the constructor body (after it has been default initialized if it has a default constructor). Like this:

```
struct C {
    C() { i = 42; }
    int i;
};
```

The last option is usually not what you want since in that case the member will first be default constructed as part of the member initialization that happens before the body of the constructor is entered (see `struct B` above) and then you subsequently assign to it. That's irrelevant for a type like `int` that I use in these examples, but for types that are expensive to construct and assign it can matter.

You can also combine the 3 forms. For example:

```
struct D {
    D() : i{1} // this overrules the in-class initializer
    { i = 3; // assign a new value despite the fact that we constructed the object already
    }
    int i = 0; // initial value
};
```